# Ziggeo - what data is passed to webhook url?

Tags: ziggeo-api

I'd like to create a webhook that is notified when a video transcription occurs. I'm storing some of the video data on my end, and part of that is the transcription text of the video.

I have it set up to be passed as JSON

[image]

The only problem is that I don't know what that data structure looks like, this is the only information in the docs about it:

[image]

What data gets passed when the event occurs? Is it just the Video Data that you can see in the Admin view of the video?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ziggeo have a detailed Page that shows how to use the webhooks here https://support.ziggeo.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006656247-Using-Ziggeo-webhooks-aka-server-side-events

And the site have a sandbox to generate code that will retrieve the webhook data https://ziggeo.com/sandbox/webhooks (right now, it's only for PHP and NodeJS though)

Furthermore, you can use service like this https://webhook.site that would retrieve the webhook and you can inspect the sent data. Make sure you put your own unique URL created for you on the Ziggeo dashboard.

Ibnu (from Ziggeo)